# How to perform OR logic in the filters pane?

Tags: date, filter, powerbi, logical-operators, logical-or

In Power BI desktop filters pane, the filters together work as an AND condition. Is there any way to make them work like an OR condition?

Example:

DateOfJoining is greater than 1st Jan 2020 OR DateOfBirth is greater than 1st Jan 1990

Comment: There are option AND & OR available under Advanced Filtering. You can try that.

Comment: Those are for one column. I am looking for OR for multi coloum. Please see example added to question.

Comment: Create a custom measure based on selected value DateOfJoining  and DateOfBirth. Return 1 or 0 as per your requirement and then use that Measure for filtering.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should create a separate calculated column or a measure that would incorporate your filters in its logic and then use this newly created column/ measure as a filter in the filter pane. From my experience I've never come up with a way to make filters work differently than the default AND. I even doubt that would be useful to the wide majority (having in mind that there is quite natural alternative).

Answer (score 0):

Is it that what you are looking for?
[image]

Comment: This is for one column. I am looking to apply OR on 2 columns. Please see example in question.